# Recommendation System Algorithms for Multi-entity ranking

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system, ranking

I'm looking for industry engineering or research papers tacking the problem of universally ranking disparate items. For example, one example is the Doordash recommender, which their team attempted to solve the problem of simultaneously ranking food items, restaurants, and restaurant horizontal carousels: https://doordash.engineering/2022/10/05/homepage-recommendation-with-exploitation-and-exploration/

Their approach exploits the hierarchical relationship between entities to design a universal ranker, but looking for example where this kind of relationship doesn't exist but the items are very different.

Thanks